# Spreadsheet help, Do I need VBA or can I do this in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Really appreciate you guys taking a look. Basically, what I want to do is for each item as long as the item is the same, we can add up Company Quantities. So for Orange, company A we have a quantity of 3+2+1, Company B for Orange is just 1, Company C for Orange is 4+5. Once the item changes, then we have Company A for Pear is 3+2. Let me know if this needs any further explaining... I am struggling coming up how to do it within excel and through VBA.

```
Company Item    Quantity
A   Orange  1
A   Orange  3
A   Orange  2
B   Orange  1
C   Orange  4
C   Orange  5
A   Apple   2
B   Apple   1
C   Apple   2
D   Apple   4
A   Pear    3
A   Pear    2
B   Pear    1
B   Pear    4
C   Pear    5
C   Pear    3
```

Comment: Did you try google for an answer? Can you post a well formatted version of your table and what you've tried up to now? In any case, what you might be looking for is SUMIF() or SUMIFS()

Comment: Just updated the format. I tried googling... I may be just asking the question wrong.

Comment: As I mentioned, please google SUMIFS ... basically it takes 2+ parameters (Company, Item) and a range to SUM (quantity)

Comment: Right, but I want to just output one number per group.. For example A Orange = 6 in another column, B Orange = 1. I want one function that I could just drag down, otherwise it would be easier to just manually do it than write individual SUMIFS

Comment: That's the entire point of SUMIFS. See Grade Bacon's answer below. Please research it and try a few things before saying this isn't what you want.

Comment: @SpaceSteak - I think this may be a case where someone believes it is easier to argue in a comment area until the other party gives up and does their work for them than actually do any work themselves. For some trolls it seems like a form of personal victory.

Comment: You guys are brutal... I understand what Sumifs does, but instead of having A Orange 6 for 3 rows, I only want  A Orange 6 for the last row of Company A Orange. A Sumifs formula would give me 6,6,6,1,9,9 for the first 6 rows. My experience with excel is very limited so I would appreciate it if you didn't think I was "trolling" @Jeeped

Comment: in D2, `=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2, A2, B$2:B2, B2)=COUNTIFS(A:A, A2,B:B, B2), SUMIFS(C:C,A:A, A2,B:B, B2), "")`.

Answer (score 2):

As SpaceSteak specifically pointed out, this is just the SUMIFS formula. SUMIFS looks at a range to sum, then, given any number of ranges of the same size, it checks to see which rows/columns meet all identified criteria. Like so:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"A",B:B,"Orange")
```

Or, if you have the company name in cell D1 and the fruit in cell E1, this would look like:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,D1,B:B,E1)
```